# In which lifecycle method are manifest properties applied to activity? and are those inherited from other extending activities?

Tags: android

We know that xml layout code gets parsed to java view object in `setContentView` call. But I was just curious to know when are the manifest properties (like `windowSoftInputMode`, `screenOrientation` etc) are applied to the activity. I mean what lifecycle method?

Any practical explanation is more than appreciated, TIA!

Comment: Many, perhaps most, I would not expect to be tied to lifecycle methods.

Comment: In that case, In which method of activity creation are those applied? Any insights pls?

Comment: I would expect many, perhaps most, to have nothing to do with your particular `Activity` subclass or any of your Java/Kotlin code, or any "method of activity creation". Instead, they would be used by the OS itself to control how it manages the activity, the activity's window, the IPC between other components and the activity, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think manifest will get attached to the app in its installation period. like when we start installing an app , it will read its manifest file to check ;
where to install 
What permissions to show
which activity is a launcher for the app
for more information:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro